# How to delete characters in a list after a certain character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like so:

`[' abc \t 123 \n', 'def \t 456 \n', 'ghi \t 789 \n']`

I'm trying to delete every character after `\t` so that I'm left with

`['abc','def','ghi']`

Comment: ok. what is the issue are facing ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

only one opportunity out of many:

```
data = [' abc \t 123 \n', 'def \t 456 \n', 'ghi \t 789 \n']

converted = [x.replace(" ", "").split("\t")[0] for x in data]
# or like this:
# converted = [x.split("\t")[0].strip() for x in data]

print(converted)
#['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s = [i.replace('\t', '') for i in s]
```

Here, just replace your target character. and if your want to remove `\n`, do it again:

```
s = [i.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') for i in s]
```

Because you only care about the alpha. so do it like this:

```
s2 = [''.join(i for i in myStr if not i.isdigit()) for myStr in s]
```

For now you got:

```
[' abc   ', 'def   ', 'ghi   ']
```

Still! not you desire, right?

```
s3 = [i.strip() for i in s2]
```

For now, you will happy to see your result:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for-loop and remove all values after \t

```
    values = [' abc \t 123 \n', 'def \t 456 \n', 'ghi \t 789 \n']
    result = []

    for element in values:
        idx = element.index('\t')
        text = element[:idx]
        result.append(text.strip())
```

the .strip method removes spaces from the final values. The result looks like this:

```
     ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```